# Why is my raster offset after I use a tool such as Reclassify?

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and have noticed a strange problem.  Often,though not always, when I use a tool such as Polygon to Raster, Reclassify, or Mosaic to New Raster, the resulting raster layer is offset just a bit- either it's too high or low by about half a pixel.  The projection is exactly the same, the layers just don't quite line up.  The strangest thing is that it doesn't always happen.  Anyone else run into this problem or have a solution?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Check that you have you set the snap raster in the raster analysis environment variables.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for my raster analysis but know it's happening with polygon layers as well.  For example, I'm trying to project a layer and the outcome is slightly offset.